# h5py errors after installation

Tags: python, macos, numpy, enthought, h5py

I'm trying to install h5py on Mac OSX and use it's group and dataset features, but I'm having an issue. On its installation webpage it says the easiest way for beginners to use it on Mac is to install Anaconda, so that's what I did since I would still consider myself an inexperienced programmer. Anyway, after installing Anaconda and typing the following script into iPython Notebook, I get an "image not found error."

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5" , "w")
```

Here is the full error (its pretty long):

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-65d72c32bd56> in <module>()
----> 1 import h5py
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
      4 f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "w")

/Users/wlentzii/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py in     <module>()
     21 _errors.silence_errors()
     22 
---> 23 from . import _conv
     24 _conv.register_converters()
     25 

h5py/h5t.pxd in init h5py._conv (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_conv.c:6961)()

h5py/numpy.pxd in init h5py.h5t (-------src-dir--------/h5py/h5t.c:19623)()

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    166         return loader(*packages, **options)
    167 
--> 168     from . import add_newdocs
    169     __all__ = ['add_newdocs', 'ModuleDeprecationWarning']
    170 

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15     ###############################################################################

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from . import scimath as emath
---> 18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode
     20 from .utils import *

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in <module>()
     17 from numpy.lib.function_base import trim_zeros, sort_complex
     18 from numpy.lib.type_check import iscomplex, real, imag
---> 19 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
     20 
     21 class RankWarning(UserWarning):

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
     48 from .info import __doc__
     49 
---> 50 from .linalg import *
     51 
     52 from numpy.testing import Tester

/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in <module>()
     27     )
     28 from numpy.lib import triu, asfarray
---> 29 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
     30 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     31 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib    /python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/wlentzii/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: I apologize if there is already a question very similar to this. My problem is that since I'm pretty inexperienced I have trouble extrapolating from similar problems to my own...

Comment: looks like a `numpy` and `enthought` issue, not so much `h5py`.

Comment: Thanks, it had something to do with installing Anaconda, because this actually happened to some scripts that already worked before I installed that. I uninstalled Anaconda and now iPython works like normal again, I just have to properly figure out how to get h5py. I'll probably try the "non-beginners" installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback shows that you are using Canopy's Python, not Anaconda's.  Either (1) make sure Anaconda appears in your system path before Canopy or (2) use Canopy's package manager to install h5py.  Since you have Canopy installed already, and that's what appears first in your path already, that might be the easiest choice for you.  You can either use the graphical Package Manager (reachable from the Welcome screen) or install h5py from the command-line

`enpkg h5py`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I ended up using homebrew/science to get h5py.